# What does the selector syntax mean in $( "<div/>" ).text( message )

Tags: jquery

What does the selector `<div/>` syntax mean in this code?  I've seen selectors like `div` or `#someId` but I'm confused what the `<div/>` means

```
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
```

Comment: it is create an div attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "create a jQuery-wrapped div element on the fly".

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

From the above:

> **jQuery( html [, ownerDocument] )**
>
> Description: Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string
>   of raw HTML.

Later...

> When the parameter has a single tag, such as `$('<img />')` or
>   `$('<a></a>')`, jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript
>   `createElement()` function.

So basically, it's like doing:

```
$(document.createElement("div")).text("blahblah");
```

Comment: +1 The point here is that `<div/>` is not actually a selector.

Comment: You can also use $("<tagname>") to create any element - no need to close the tag

Comment: Also @LedZeppelin, take a look here http://robflaherty.github.com/jquery-annotated-source/docs/01-core.html#section-25 to see how $ (which in fact runs the jQuery.fn.init function) processes the various parameters it accepts

Answer (score 1):

It will create a new `<div/>` element and prepend it to the `#log` element.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a new `div` tag and prepends it to `log`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the jquery function will not actually query for DIV elements but will create an jquery wrapped element of type `<div></div>` on which you can work on and append to the DOM eventually.

In your case, the code will create jquery object representing a DIV element, set its innerText to what the message variable contains and prepend it to the element with ID "log".

Answer (score 1):

`$('<div/>')` will not select a div from your html, but create a new one. Also it can be written like `$('<div></div>')`, first one is just a shorthand for second.

Answer (score 0):

`<div />` indicates that the div is a self closing div. It's basically shorthand for `$('<div></div>')`.

Any browser that supports XHTML supports the self-closing syntax on all elements.