# jQuery . what does $('<img/>') mean?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the selector syntax mean in $( “<div/>” ).text( message )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127898/what-does-the-selector-syntax-mean-in-div-text-message)

I've searched but couldn't find any info on this... including the jQuery reference...

What does `$('<img/>')` mean in jQuery?
I am familiar with `$('img')` only.

I have come across this code in this article:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/11/16/hover-slide-effect/

But in the code, when I replace one with the other, it stops working, so I guess they are not the same.

Also, the last piece of code:

```
.attr('src',$this.attr('src'));
```

what is it for? It seems redudant, but it also fails if I remove it.
Can anyone elaborate on this?

Thanks

Comment: As so often, the documentation provides an explanation :) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: The `.attr(` is called on the new `<img>` tag created, whereas `$this` is an `img` that already exists. Remember that `$this` is not the same as `$(this)`.

Comment: @FelixKling I'd like a closing reason "is in the standard doc"...

Comment: @dystroy: Me too!! With the possibility  to link to the respective section of documentation. Maybe we should suggest that, but I would be surprised if it hasn't already.

Comment: But of course the problem would be to avoid sounding too much like "RTFM"... That might be dangerous : It's so easy to be arrogant...

Comment: @dystroy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason ... or all we need is just a very good canonical answer.

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks. The problem was that I thought it was a selector, so it made finding it in the manual difficult.

Comment: @nunomira It's true that jquery functions are maybe a little too much versatile, it may be confusing.

Comment: @dystroy, yes, exactly. What's more ridiculous is that after reading the explanation I remembered that I had learnt about it before! Won't forget again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(anyHtmlCode)` builds a jQuery wrapped set of elements built from the HTML you provide.

[From the documentation :](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

> If a string is passed as the parameter to `$()`, jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has `<tag ... >` somewhere
>   within the string). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector
>   expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an
>   HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described
>   by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers
>   to these elements. You can perform any of the usual jQuery methods on
>   this object

The line

```
$someElement.attr('src',$this.attr('src'));
```

sets the src of $someElement to be the same as those of $this.

Comment: And these images that are created are never added to the page, correct? They are used to force the the image to load with the
attr('src',$this.attr('src')) piece of code, and to have a reference to each of the images?

Comment: It seems so but I don't want to read the whole article. Once you know the basics of jQuery I find it easier to write the needed code than to adapt or parameterize a generally too big plugin. This seems a lot of code for a simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

`$('<img/>')` is creating a new image tag .
it is similar to

```
document.createElement('img')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('<img />')` actually creates a new `img` element and wraps it in a jQuery object, whereas `$('img')` selects all `img` elements on the page.

`$('img').attr('src',$this.attr('src'))` sets the first matched `img` element's `src` attribute.